# Build jenkins pipeline when someone pushes to git repository

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to trigger my pipeline whenever someone is pushing something to the git repository. I am **not** using GitHub.
Is this possible within Jenkins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is, you can set your `Build Trigger` to `Poll SCM` and `* * * * *`

As per below:

[image]

Comment: Works fine. Thank you very much !

Comment: There are other options: which platform do you use for git? With gitlab and gitswarm a plugin exist which notify jenkins that there is a new commit in a specific branch

Answer (score 1):

Poll SCM is one option. The other is to use webhooks.

SCM Side:
https://help.github.com/articles/about-webhooks/
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/manage-webhooks-735643732.html

Jenkins Side:
https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/224543927-GitHub-Integration-Webhooks

Essentially you assign a webhook to the repo and it will be triggered based on your criteria (say push event) to let jenkins know. Jenkins pipelines can then kick off.

We use https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Branch+Source+Plugin
Which dynamically creates the jenkins job and even configures the webhook for you, when it detects a Jenkinsfile. (there is also a bitbucket version https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Bitbucket+Branch+Source+Plugin)

Answer (score 0):

Webhooks are very practical and I suggest to take a look to them.
I am using gitea and jenkins is configured with Gitea Plugin. It automatically creates a webhook on gitea. The following commits are automatically notified by gitea to jenkins.